# PHP: how to know if output already started?

Tags: php, header

I use the same php script for **including** and for **ajax** loading. It is some random catalog items which are loaded with the page and can be loaded with ajax. I need to use `header()` function there only if it is loaded via ajax.

When I use header function and the output already started I get php warning about it. How does php know that output already started? What is the best way to determine that, and not to call header function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

```
// If no headers are sent, send one
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('...');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just what I needed. And by the way why exit?

Comment: The use of exit is straight from the referenced PHP manual for a 'header: Location' call which requires it. In your case you should not add it, or you will break the output.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I copied it straight from the manual and forgot to remove it :)

Answer (score 6):

There's an easy built-in for that:

```
if (!headers_sent()) {
    header('Your header here');
}
```

Not much more to add :)

Answer (score 3):

One option is to call `ob_start()` at the beginning, which [buffers all your output](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php). That way you can send headers any time.

Answer (score 2):

[`headers_sent()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) returns `true` if you cannot send additional headers.

Answer (score 0):

If you sent anything to client, the output started.

For example even a single html tag, it's already output.

You can either structure your application so that this doesn't happen,
or you can turn on output buffering:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the empty line before the code starts and add exit;
after your output ends.

Comment: There's no code in the question - how do you know what's in there and what isn't? Most of the current answers suggest using `headers_sent()` - is there a reason why your suggestion might be better?