# how can i find out if the php output already started?

Tags: php, output-buffering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: how to know if output already started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752683/php-how-to-know-if-output-already-started)

I would like to find out if there is **already generated output in the buffer** before I start the session.

In PHP, an output that started before the session started always creates a warning, for example a bug in the controller creates this output:

> Warning:
>   fopen(/tmp/test.txt)
>   [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/app/controllers/test_controller.php on line 836
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at test.php:836) in layouts/default.thtml on line 18

This is not the problem, I like that warning so I find out some bugs.

But my layout is designed like that there is a fixed bar at the top of the page that covers the first warning. so I would like to find out if there is already generated output in the buffer before I start the session, so I can quit adding the style fixed to that bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function for that: [`headers_sent`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php).