# Automated grep search for BOM with Cannot modify header information headers already sent

Tags: php, grep, byte-order-mark

> Warning: **Cannot modify header information - headers already sent** by (output started at example.php:1)

It looks like there is an unlimited amount of these questions and they keep coming. I agree that in most cases [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) [is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561959/how-can-i-find-out-if-the-php-output-already-started) [out there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685646/how-can-i-find-out-where-my-output-started) already.

I ran into the same issue myself. There was a mysterious character in the output that prevented me from setting the headers. Since it was a big application that has a lot of files, going through each one to search for it was not an option.

I believe the issue is due to a BOM or an extra space before the `<?php` opening tag somewhere in one of the included files. When I open the file referred to in the error message it looks like there's nothing wrong with it.

How do I find where the issue is?

Comment: You start by reading the error message, because it TELLS you where the problem is: example.php, line #1.

Comment: You end by reading the question, because it tells you `When I open the file referred to in the error message it looks like there's nothing wrong with it`

Comment: if it's line #1, then it's whitespace before your opening `<?php` tag: either a bom, or actual white space, e.g. `[space]<?php`. **ANYTHING** outside of `<?php ... ?>` tag sets is considered output. Remember: There's no such thing as a PHP script. There's only files which have PHP code blocks within them. Anything outside the code blocks is output.

Comment: Thanks. I presumed it could've been any other included or parent file. I just shared my experience in solving this because I couldn't find an existing solution. Is there anything wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the automated solution that has helped me to track down that character. SSH access required.

```
grep -v -R "^<?php" /home/public_html/ --include \*.php | grep "<?php"
```

`grep` is a very useful tool that is able to recursively search through files and folders contents.

- `-v` means *exclude*, i.e. output the opposite of whatever matches the regular expression I'll pass later
- `-R` means recursively, i.e. search inside the folder provided and inside it's subdirectories
- `"^<?php"` is the expression that matches the lines that begin (`^`) precicely with the PHP opening tag. Again, `-v` is used to invert this so I get the lines that do not - which is what I'm after.
- `/home/public_html/` is the folder with all of my website files
- `--include \*.php` we're searching inside the .php files only
- `grep "<?php"` is a trick that captures the first lines of the file only

Thing is, that the `-v` flag inverts the search results and outputs whatever doesn't match the expression. So if a file has 1000 lines with only first one being the `<?php` opening tag, that'll output all 999 because thouse do not match the regexp. Since I need to look at the first line only, I'm forwarding the greps output into another grep that filters the results one more time and makes sure I get the lines that have another condition I pass - which is again, the opening tag. This is a workaround which this way limits greps output to the first line only.

Hope this helps